# drbd both nodes inconsistent, and outofdate, how to fix?

Tags: drbd

This is a setup I inherited, and that is really old (running drbd 8.3). I tried `drbdadm connect drbd0`, `drbdadm primary -f drbd0`, but everything comes back with `Need access to UpToDate data`.

I presume that is because of being Inconsistent.

```
[root@node-01 ~]# drbd-overview
  0:drbd0  StandAlone Secondary/Unknown   Inconsistent/Outdated r-----
  1:drbd1  Connected  Secondary/Secondary UpToDate/UpToDate     C      r-----

[root@node-02 ~]# drbd-overview
  0:drbd0  WFConnection Secondary/Unknown   Inconsistent/DUnknown C r-----
  1:drbd1  Connected    Secondary/Secondary UpToDate/UpToDate     C r-----
```

How can I fix this, without nuking the data on it?

When I did `drbdadm connect drbd0` the system log says:

```
block drbd0: conn( StandAlone -> Unconnected )
block drbd0: Starting receiver thread (from drbd0_worker [6860])
block drbd0: receiver (re)started
block drbd0: conn( Unconnected -> WFConnection )
block drbd0: Handshake successful: Agreed network protocol version 96
block drbd0: conn( WFConnection -> WFReportParams )
block drbd0: Starting asender thread (from drbd0_receiver [21821])
block drbd0: data-integrity-alg: <not-used>
block drbd0: drbd_sync_handshake:
block drbd0: self AA586D9040BXXXX:7DF55F42BF95XXXX:7DF45F42BF95XXXX:DC31D449C727XXXX bits:416 flags:0
block drbd0: peer 7DF55F42BF9XXXX:0000000000000000:DC31D449C727EE27:DC30D449C727XXXX bits:416 flags:0
block drbd0: uuid_compare()=1 by rule 70
block drbd0: I shall become SyncSource, but I am inconsistent!
block drbd0: conn( WFReportParams -> Disconnecting )
block drbd0: error receiving ReportState, l: 4!
block drbd0: asender terminated
block drbd0: Terminating asender thread
block drbd0: Connection closed
block drbd0: conn( Disconnecting -> StandAlone )
block drbd0: receiver terminated
block drbd0: Terminating receiver thread
```

Comment: Node 01 is currently in "StandAlone". Try to re-establish a connection firstly with 'drbdadm connect drbd0'. Afterwards, check the logs for some additional clues.

Comment: @Dok: I included the syslog output

Comment: @raarts: I saw you join #drbd on Freenode and ask this question. I would have answered you there if you would have stuck around (I'm on PDT time) ;) Either way, my answer below _should_ be what you're looking for. If it doesn't work for some reason let me know in a comment and I'll help you through it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Neither node has `UpToDate` data, so DRBD will not be able to go `Primary` without some convincing. You'll need to force a node into Primary.

Which ever node you run the following command on *should* become the `SyncSource`, so be sure you choose the node you believe to have good data.

`drbdadm -- --overwrite-data-of-peer primary <resource>`

If you're not sure, I would `disconnect` the resource on both nodes so they're both `StandAlone`, run the above command on one node, promote that node to `Primary`, and then inspect the data. Then repeat on the other node. Once you know where the good data is, you can demote both sides and resolve the split-brain in the correct direction by telling the split-brain victim to discard his data using: `drbdadm -- --discard-my-data connect <resource>`, and simply connecting the split-brain survivor: `drbdadm connect <resource>`.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Matt, thanks, I did, and my Xen cluster (which runs on this drbd) came back online, but I now get the following on node1: `0:drbd0  Connected Primary/Secondary   UpToDate/Inconsistent C r-----` and this on node2: `0:drbd0  Connected Secondary/Primary   Inconsistent/UpToDate`. This means it's still not syncing?

Comment: @raarts: On the `Secondary` node run the following:  `drbdadm disconnect drbd0 && drbdadm connect drbd0`. Is this version of DRBD older than 8.3.8.1? There was a race condition fixed in 8.3.8.1 that caused similar symptoms.

Comment: I ran it, it started syncing (was done in 20 seconds: `[=========>..........] sync'ed: 53.1% (435124/923908)K` , two machines connected over 100Mb, but ended up in the same state. Syslog said: `Resync done (total 43 sec; paused 0 sec; 21484 K/sec) 640 failed blocks`. Am I in trouble?

Comment: Ok, I found the problem. Disk I/O errors on the first node. Thanks for helping!